# Find an example of function where $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)+f(2x))=0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\neq 0.$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

when 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)+f(2x))=0$$ 
but 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\neq 0$$
I've tried some trig functions and logs but couldn't find an example
help would be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: You can have an example where the first limit is zero and the second doesn't exist, but not an example where the first limit is zero and the second exists but is non-zero.

Comment: You can cook up an example where $f(x)+f(2x)$ is identically zero, but the second limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to construct an $f$ so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) + f(2x) = 0$ (in fact $f(x) + f(2x)$ is identically $0$) but $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

Edit: Choose $f(x) = (-1)^k$ when $x = 2^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, otherwise $x = 0$. 
Then the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$ does not exist since, e.g., $2^{-k} \rightarrow 0$ but $f(2^{-k})$ alternates between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @AsafRosemarin You are right, as I realized after I saw your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

How about
$$
f(x)=\sin\left(\pi\cdot\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}\right)?
$$
As $x\to 0^+$, we have $\ln x\to -\infty$, so the $\sin$ will oscillate and not approach a limit. On the other hand, $f(x)+f(2x)=0$ for all $x>0$, so the limit is clearly zero.

If you want something defined for negative $x$ as well, replace $x$ with $|x|$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}p\cdot(-1)^{[s \text{ mod }2]},p  \text{ is an odd prime},x=\frac{2^s}{p}\\0, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
It is obvious that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) \neq 0$.
But, $f(x)+f(2x)\equiv0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=L\ne 0$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(2x)=L$ and hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(f(x)+f(2x))=2L\ne 0$.

Comment: You are right if the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists, which need not be the case.

Comment: It seems to me that OP assumed the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$.

Comment: I have found that many beginners are happy to write and manipulate expressions of the form $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ quite happily without feeling the need to prove that limit exists, or even when that limit doesn't exist.

Comment: The first limit is give and is equal to-0.